# Heap pages in /proc/<pid>/maps

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I would like to write a program that could parse
the output of `/proc/<pid>/maps` in order to classify
them into different categories:

- `Image` : the page is either a mapping of the binary or one of it's required libraries
- `Mapped file` : the page maps a specific file like a font for example
- `Stack`
- `Heap`
- `Private data`
- `Shareable`

As you might have guessed, the main idea is to develop an equivalent of sysinternals's vmmap tool
for Linux.

I'm using the `pathname` field to determine in which category a page could be associated with.

If `pathname` is the same path as `/proc/<pid>/exe` symlink, or if
it is a dependency, therefore it goes to `Image`.

If `pathname` is a file and isn't part of the Image, then it is a `Mapped File`.

If `pathname` is matching a pattern like `[stack:<tid>]` or `[heap]`,
then the page is respectively a `Stack` or a `Heap`.

While I was looking for some information about `/proc/<pid>/maps`, I came accross
this stackoverflow post [missing-heap-section-in-proc-pid-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782536/missing-heap-section-in-proc-pid-maps) , where I discovered that if you were calling malloc with the size parameter
above a certain threshold, a private anonymous mapping was created instead
of increasing the size of the Heap.

1. How can I know if an anonymous mapping is an independant heap, or something else ?
2. Should I treat all anonymous mapping as `[heap]` ? If not, how to classify them ?
3. What page could fit into the `Private Data`, and `Shareable` categories ?

Thanks !

Comment: `anonymous mapping` could be done by `mmap` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag, and it's not `[heap]`.

Comment: The thing is that heap is anonymous mapping too. There are file-backed mappings and anonymous mappings, that is all. Stack, heap - they are anonymous memory, they have separate names because of their special role or special API for handling them (sbrk)

Comment: @ChrisTsui thanks ! I learned from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816232/output-of-linux-proc-pid-maps-in-detail] that an anonymous mapping may represent a `BSS` segment for example and therefore not a `Heap`.
@AlexHoppus Do you have any idea how I could achieve the same work as `vmmap` is doing on Windows ?
Is seems that I can't rely on `/proc/<pid>/maps`.